# Deserialize from HttpRequest not working correctly in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a custom model binder to get some values from `FormData` that come from a react application. Everything works fine except for one specific property: `TenantDomainUrl`. When deseerialization occurs, this value is set to `null`, even if its sent in the request:

Image1: (just before sending the request, check the console:

[image]

The custom model binder code is this:

```
public class TenantModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Tenant))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var model = new Tenant();

                if (!actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "WebRequeest content 'multipart/form-data' is valid");
                }
                else
                {
                    var provider = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

                    //var fileContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals("file"));
                    var fileContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals(@"""file"""));
                    if (fileContent == null)
                    {
                        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Section 'file' is missed");
                    }

                    //var modelContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals("model"));
                    var modelContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals(@"""model"""));
                    if (modelContent == null)
                    {
                        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Section 'model' is missed");
                    }

                    if (fileContent != null && modelContent != null)
                    {
                        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tenant>(
                            await modelContent.ReadAsStringAsync());

                        model.CertificateFile = fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                    }
                }

                return model;
            });

            task.Wait();

            bindingContext.Model = task.Result;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And the 2nd image after deserialization

[image]

I dont think I actually need to post the REACT JS Code

Update:

readasstring returns the json correctly with the value, but after deserialization the property is null:

[image]

Update 2, tenant class

```
public class Tenant
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string TenantDomainUrl { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

        public string SiteCollectionTestUrl { get; set; }

        public string CertificatePassword { get; set; }

        public byte[] CertificateFile { get; set; }


        public Uri CertificatePath { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your `Tenant` class look like? Does your TenantDomainUrl have a public set accessor?

Comment: please see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `JsonProperty` it will not be read from the `TenantDomainUrl` `JSON` value, but from `id`.

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
```

Remove the attribute, or alter the posted `JSON`.

**UPDATE**

In your first picture above I notice

```
 "id":null
```

Refering to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468359/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-tenantmanage/51468711#51468711) on this topic, make sure to pass this `id` via your `FormData` with the key `id` and the value set, something like here below.

```
data.append("model", JSON.stringify({ "id": "your-id-goes-here" }}
```

Comment: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468975/adding-a-cosmosdb-entity-unable-to-resolve-id-for-entity-of-type-tenant

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

If the `[JsonProperty("id")]` must stay on **TenantDomainUrl**, you need to change the JSON you post to this endpoint to have a key of **id** instead of **TenantDomainUrl**. Something like this

```
{"id":"cm.microsoft.com","ApplicationId":"a21-fan-...", /* other properties in your JSON */}
```

instead of

```
{"TenantDomainUrl":"cm.microsoft.com","ApplicationId":"a21-fan-...", /* other properties in your JSON */}
```

Comment: I am using Cosmonaut nuget package to insert the Tenant information into CosmosDB, according to the developer I have to put JsonProperty in the field that should be the id. Please see my previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468975/adding-a-cosmosdb-entity-unable-to-resolve-id-for-entity-of-type-tenant

Comment: In that case, you need to change the JSON you send to the server to have a key of "id" instead of "TenantDomainUrl" then.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your previous question. In the future, it is best to include all details in a single question (instead of having details in another question)